# how to automated a BUILD task

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, msbuild-task

I need help about how to automated a task with MSBUILD.

I wrote a small command line program that process files and I want integrate it at the moment of BUILD the solution.

The program itself is used like this:

```
Processor.exe inputFile.txt outputFile.txt –p
```

-p of course represents some parameters.

Is there a simple way to make visual studio to run this exe AFTER each Buildup??

To be honest I research a lot about the MSBUILD, but there is so much information out there, that it overwhelmed me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different solutions but in your case the best is probably with custom **AfterBuild** target and **Exec** task. You should add it to your cproj file after Microsoft.CSharp.targets get imported.

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<Target Name ="AfterBuild">
  <Exec Command="Processor.exe inputFile.txt outputFile.txt –p"  />
</Target>
```

You can read more about Exec Task here:

[Exec Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28%22HTTP://SCHEMAS.MICROSOFT.COM/DEVELOPER/MSBUILD/2003#EXEC%22%29;k%28%22HTTP://SCHEMAS.MICROSOFT.COM/DEVELOPER/MSBUILD/2003#TARGET%22%29;k%28VS.XMLEDITOR%29&rd=true)

Comment: @StanislawSwierc Looks like the link is dead, haven't found an updated one yet.